# Would a native speaker use the word "dismiss" to talk about "school"?

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

In our country people use **dismissal time** to talk about **end of a day at school**:

> What is the **dismissal time** of this school?

And sometimes:

> What time does the school **dismisses?**

I have checked few *online dictionaries* but none have used the word **dismiss** to mean **end of a day at school.**

I wish to know that **how far it is appropriate to the ears of a native English speaker.**

Comment: It's true that teachers often say ***Class [is] dismissed*** to indicate that the lesson is over and students can now leave the classroom. But we wouldn't use either the verb ***to dismiss*** or the noun ***dismissal*** for your context. I think the most likely way of phrasing the question would be *What time does [the] school **finish**?* I personally wouldn't normally include the article *(**the**)* there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Dismissal (n) and dismiss (v) are used idiomatically in U.S. schools, often in writing (on a website or parent information guide). One will often see "Dismissal: 2:30 PM" or "Students are dismissed at 2:30 PM." It would sound a bit stiff and formal verbally; one will more often hear "What time does school get out?" or "What time do you get out of school?"

Comment: When I was in school here in New England in the 1980's it certainly was used. Your first example is the sort of thing we said. But your second example seems odd. You have the school doing the dismissing. We would have asked: "What time is school dismissed." or "At what time do they dismiss school."

Comment: One potential problem with ***dismiss*** in such contexts is it can also be used to mean *[semi-] **permanently** excluded / sent away*, as per [Something is radically wrong when five per cent of our University students are dismissed at one time for inefficiency. The University will not cure the disease by wholesale dismissal of students; that is merely treating the symptoms.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22University+students+are+dismissed+at+one+time%22)

Comment: as a british speaker it sounds very wrong.

Comment: @WendyG what in your opinion is correct one?

Answer (score 1):

British English does use: the teacher dismissed the class, so does AmE.

**Lenton Times Magazine** - Memories of Cottesmore School ...www.lentontimes.co.uk › memories › memories_240805
**

> I started to cry and the teacher dismissed the class and put his arm
>   around my shoulder and told me not to worry. He issued me with a
>   blow-up mattress and I ... [the teacher dismissed the class](https://www.lentontimes.co.uk/memories/memories_240805.htm)

**

And:

> **The teacher dismissed the class at the end of lesson.**

[UK, dismissed the class](https://www.expresspublishing.co.uk/assets/microsites/ro/pdfs/UPupperTS_full_book.pdf)

A person dismisses a class or group of people. School does not "dismiss"

But, in idiomatic English:

- What time does your school get out?
- What time does your school let out?
- What time does your school day end?

formal: At what time does your teacher dismiss your class?

"dismissal time" is OK, but only in formal terms.

When you check the word dismiss in a dictionary, it is about people doing the action, not things.

Also, bear in mind: the teacher **was dismissed**. or The school dismissed the teacher = fired.

Answer (score 0):

> I have checked few online dictionaries but none have used the word dismiss to mean end of a day at school.

The top two (and certainly many more) search results use it as an example sentence.

[merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismiss)

Definition of dismiss

transitive verb

1: to permit or cause to leave

dismiss the visitors

**Class is dismissed.**

[www.dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dismiss)

Dismiss

verb (used with object)

to direct (an assembly of persons) to disperse or go:

**I dismissed the class early.**

It's perfectly normal to use the word "dismiss" in relation to class and school.